# Merge all Nested Json Objects

Tags: c#, json

I have got a following json. I want to merge all nested json objects into one.

```
    [
      {
        "2": "a",
        "3": "a"
      },
      {
        "2": "f",
        "3": "a",
        "4": "p"
      },
      {
        "2": "n",
        "3": "o",
        "4": "t"
      }
    ]
```

so, the output of the above `json` would be

```
[  
   {  
      "0":"a",
      "1":"a",
      "2":"f",
      "3":"a",
      "4":"p",
      "5":"n",
      "6":"o",
      "7":"t"
   }
]
```

I tried to parse the json array and then add all values and append it to another array. However, is there any other elegant solution to merge all nested json objects to one?

Comment: Is this in c# or visual studio?

Comment: its a c# code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you need to change indices, manual merging is unavoidable.

E.g. `SelectMany` from Linq could be used for merging as:

```
var input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>[]>(@"
[
  {
    ""2"": ""a"",
    ""3"": ""a""
  },
  {
    ""2"": ""f"",
    ""3"": ""a"",
    ""4"": ""p""
  },
  {
    ""2"": ""n"",
    ""3"": ""o"",
    ""4"": ""t""
  }
]");

var result = input
    .SelectMany(d => d.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).Select(kvp => kvp.Value))
    .Select((value, index) => new {index, value})
    .ToDictionary(iv => iv.index, iv => iv.value);

 var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

Comment: I get an error called, `SelectMany` . which framework are you using here?

Comment: `Linq`, add this at the beginning of file: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: it works like a charm. However, the resultant json order is not exactly the same. Is there any ways to fix it?

Comment: The actual json that I'm using is rumbled.

Comment: Ok, and you can try to use SortedDictionary to mandate the order by keys: `var jsonResult2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new SortedDictionary<int, string>(result));`

Comment: I just removed `OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool called json .net
Check the following code :

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(model.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(sw, model);
        JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(@"{
         'FirstName': 'John',
         'LastName': 'Smith',
         'Enabled': false,
         'Roles': [ 'User' ]
          }");
        JObject o2 = JObject.Parse(@"{
         'Enabled': true,
         'Roles': [ 'User', 'Admin' ]
          }");

        o1.Merge(o2, new JsonMergeSettings
        {
            // union array values together to avoid duplicates
            MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union
        });

        string json = o1.ToString();
        // {
        //   "FirstName": "John",
        //   "LastName": "Smith",
        //   "Enabled": true,
        //   "Roles": [
        //     "User",
        //     "Admin"
        //   ]
        // }
```

Please Check Link :
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm

Comment: This still involves parsing  the Json array and merging the individual Json Objects to a new JsonObject.